# Magento - language switching back when I change the page

Tags: magento

I got a problem. when I changing language from dropdown it switch to the language I want. I saw the URL append with ?_store=thai&_from_store=default

but the problem is once I go to another page it switch back into default language (English). and

"?_store=thai&_from_store=default" is gone.

how can i fix this issue. I dont want it switch until user select the dropdown language.

I try to research many keyword on google, but can't find the solution.

Note:
Im using Magento 1.8.1.0_3

Thks

Comment: I can fix now, it just happen on localhost. after I uploaded on server. it's working good.